# Appropriate UML diagram for objects in a process

Tags: uml, diagram, diagramming

I would like to know if there exists an appropriate UML-diagram to depict sth I would describe as ***"object-flow"***, similiar to the example below:

[image: UML-like diagram for objects in a process]

It's very similiar to an activity diagram, only the focus is on objects/entities here, not on activities. IMO, an activity diagram is not the best choice to model the above nicely, and I don't know what else to chose. I would like to use UML however, whenever possible.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your diagram would work as a UML 2 activity diagram by putting the verbs in rounded boxes. Because of the activity diagram token semantics, you don't even need an explicit start and end. What's the problem?

Comment: Problem: in my (special) case, focus is - as I said - on objects, not activites. Yes, activity diagram *could* work, but not very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks pretty much exactly like a [dataflow diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram).  But they're not UML. I think Activity Diagrams are the closest you'll find in UML.  Activity Diagrams do support Object Flow specifically - have a look in the [spec](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta1/PDF).  But it looks like a DFD is better fit given your example.

hth.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with DFD. How cool is it, that I came up with almost exactly the same! ^^ Activity diagramm would work, but not very well (in this case!). However, at least DFD is *a* standard, even if it's not UML, but that's ok. Thank you very much!